# Gnosis UI display decoded transaction details

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am creating transactions (both simple and multisend) to send to my Gnosis Safe using the `@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk` and `@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client` Node.js packages. I can see the transactions show up in the gnosis-safe.io UI, but the transaction data is shown as a hex encoded string. Is there a way for the UI to decode the transaction so that the name of the function and the function inputs are displayed in a human-readable format, giving the Safe owners more visibility into what they are approving?

I notice that when I use the Transaction Builder app, the transactions are decoded, presumably because the ABI is uploaded when creating transactions that way. Is there a similar way to upload the ABI when using either of the previously mentioned Node.js packages to create/propose transactions?

Comment: what contracts are you using? are they verified on etherscan or sourcify?

Comment: For now, I am just using custom test contracts that I created in Remix and deployed to Rinkeby. They are not verified on etherscan or sourcify, but transactions from the Transaction Builder that target those contracts are still decoded in the UI. In production I will be interacting with some contracts that are verified on etherscan and some that are not.